# lsp-rust-analyzer ignores edition value in Cargo.toml

Tags: lsp, rust

When talking about Emacs configuration, the [rust-analyzer manual](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#emacs) mentions

> [...] this excellent [guide](https://robert.kra.hn/posts/2021-02-07_rust-with-emacs/) from [@rksm](https://github.com/rksm).

Which I followed to good effect, in particular:

```lisp
  (use-package lsp-mode
    :commands lsp
    :custom
    ;; what to use when checking on-save. "check" is default,
    ;; I prefer clippy.
    (lsp-rust-analyzer-cargo-watch-command "clippy")
    (lsp-eldoc-render-all t)
    (lsp-idle-delay 0.6)
    (lsp-rust-analyzer-server-display-inlay-hints t)
    :custom-face
    (lsp-rust-analyzer-inlay-face ((t (:foreground "dim gray"))))
    :config
    (add-hook 'lsp-mode-hook 'lsp-ui-mode))

  (use-package lsp-ui
    :commands lsp-ui-mode
    :custom
    (lsp-ui-peek-always-show t)
    (lsp-ui-sideline-show-hover nil) ; I found this confusing
    (lsp-ui-doc-enable nil))
```

However when having an `async fn` in my code, for example as suggested by [the rocket.rs guide](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/overview/#async-routes),

Rust analyzer is complaining about:

```
error[E0670]: `async fn` is not permitted in Rust 2015
  --> .../hello-rocket/src/main.rs:16:28
   |
16 | #[get("/delay/<seconds>")] async fn delay(seconds: u64) -> String {
   |                            ^^^^^ to use `async fn`, switch to Rust 2018 or later
   |
   = help: set `edition = "2018"` in `Cargo.toml`
   = note: for more on editions, read https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide
```

despite the fact that I already have in my `Cargo.toml`:

```rust
edition = "2018"
```

My code compiles just fine, and `rust-analyzer diagnostics $PWD` seems to complete without errors.

So I guess my question is: **How should I tell rust-analyzer via `lsp-rust-analyzer` to consider my `Cargo.toml` for the value of `edition`?**

Comment: Try to use the equivalent raw identifier syntax: r#async - from https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/edition-guide/editions/index.html.

Comment: @Ian, this doesn't makes it any better. In fact after adding `r#async` this no longer compiles. As noted above the original code compiles without errors (or warnings), but `lsp-rust-analyzer` still complains. So it seems like an Emacs configuration issue, not a Rust code issue.

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to realize that `rust-analyzer` was not the one to complain, but the buffer with the error message mentioned above was `*rustfmt*`, and indeed running `rustfmt` on my source file gave me the same error.

As [suggested](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61072#issuecomment-559067298) in this (inexplicably closed) [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61072), one can convince `rustfmt` to behave by adding `edition = "2018"` to `.rustfmt.toml`.

Since I am not expecting to hack on 2015 edition code any time soon, I chosen a different (and more Emacsy) workaround:

```lisp
  (use-package rustic
    ;; ...
    :custom
    (rustic-rustfmt-config-alist '((edition . "2018")))
    ;; ...
    )
```

Hopefully, I will find a better solution by the time the 2021 edition will come to fruition.